# Can run LTDC by circular buffer for easy graph drawing on STM32F7

Tags: stm32, display, stm32f7

In stm32f746G-Discovery, I want to draw moving graph like drawing ADC output on real time.

Is it possible to make start address of LTDC buffer shifting in every single new ADC data to having graph drawing with minimum CPU intervention and memory transaction? Like by using DSP circular buffer.

One solution maybe is to copy `LTDCbuffer` by DMA from one `&LTDCbuffer+1` to `&LTDCbuffer` itself. And correcting the last vertical line of LCD. But maybe DMA use memory bandwidth.

### Update

New solution I think it's better to duplicate the buffer and shifting adress of buffer (window) in every data update. this shifting procedure involve 2x buffer size(because I set shifting periode equal to one window or buffer size).Because data in every row shifting back(left) in LCD in this way, in every update, just adjusting one new column at the right most and construct one new column (by dma2d, in worst case) in other buffer. After completing each window shifting equal to it's length we have constructed same shape ready to jumping to it and progress the graph. Though I want to save matrix of data equal to LCD horizon width 480 and I opted instead of shifting them by DMA, to circulate and update it by it's pointer (I've heard of circular pointer or buffer in F7 but what is the starting point?). I think it's the fastest possible, doesn't it?

Comment: No, you are going to have to transform the ADC data into a pixel buffer by software.

Comment: @TomV But i think maybe there is some accelerating solution like I've updated in question, doesn't it?

Comment: The explanation isn't very clear but it seems far more complicated than just doing it in software.  The best solution is the simplest solution.

Comment: @TomV I've answered this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/604553/can-run-ltdc-by-circular-buffer-for-easy-graph-drawing-on-stm32f7 could your plz also take a look at that and I will delete this question soon.